# Dynamic validation in Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in Angular. How can I perform a required validation on `tax` only if `openDate` and `closeDate` have been populated?

```
this.employerBasicsForm = this.fb.group({
  tax: ['', [Validators.required],
  openDate: [''],
  closeDate: [''],
});
```

Comment: You can "disabled" the formControl "tax" when not openDate and closeDate and enabled if has a value

Answer (score 1):

Andrew some like

```
  employerBasicsForm = new FormGroup(
    {
      tax: new FormControl(),
      openDate: new FormControl(),
      closeDate: new FormControl()
    },
    this.validationTax()
  );

  validationTax() {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      return group.value.openDate && group.value.closeDate && !group.value.tax
        ? { required: true }
        : null;
    };
  }
```

Are not very complex. For me it's the best solution, but I also respect your opinion. Well, in this case I use a function in the own component because this validator are not used never outside the component

Answer (score 0):

Write your own ValidatorFn.  You can use it in the form group and access the form controls to check their state or use it on the form control itself and access the sibling controls through the form control parent property.

https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, no custom validator required in this case:

Make your form normally without validator to begin with:

```
this.employerBasicsForm = this.fb.group({
  tax: [''],
  openDate: [''],
  closeDate: [''],
});
```

A change method is required on both your `openDate` and `closeDate` fields:

```
<div><input type="text" formControlName="openDate" (change)="checkFields()" /></div>
<div><input type="text" formControlName="closeDate" (change)="checkFields()" /></div>
```

Then in your `checkFields` method:

```
checkFields() {

// Clear the validator every time a change occurs
this.employerBasicsForm.controls.tax.clearValidators();

// If both fields have been filled in, then make tax required
if ((this.employerBasicsForm.controls.openDate.value != null && this.employerBasicsForm.controls.closeDate.value != null))
{
  this.employerBasicsForm.controls.tax.setValidators([Validators.required]);
}

// Update the validity
this.employerBasicsForm.controls.tax.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: in general is more "robust" use a custom Validator than "play" adding/remove validators. Else you need take account if you start with the values of the form populate or not

Comment: @Eliseo I respectfully disagree. To have a custom validator for this situation would be cumbersome. Custom validators are great if you intend to have the same validation issue occur in multiple forms across your app and that all those forms are structured in the same way which you can't guarantee. The solution above would still work if the form is already populated or not.

Comment: I also respect your opinion but if you see my answer I don't see difficult create a custom validator